# Set Minimum date to UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I have a date in UILabel(like 'Dec 14, 2010). This date i want to set as minimum date of my UIDatepicker. How can i do this please reply?

Thanks
Nishant

Answer (score 15):

Convert your UILabel text in to date format using `NSDateFormatter` and put that value replacing "Date" in following example:

```
UIDatepicker *datePicker;

NSDate *Date=[NSDate date];

datePicker.minimumDate=Date;
```

Comment: @Nishant, this works, so if you have date on a label first convert that date into date object by using dateFormatter then use minimumDate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSDateFormatter` and use `setDateFormat` method for setting Date format.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:lblDate.text];

datePicker.minimumDate=date;
```

Comment: I did that but it is not working i have date like "Dec 14, 2010" and when i convert it into the date i got 'nil' value.......!!

Comment: use
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"]; You need to set your format as your date is. use comma and space at correct place.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateComponents *comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
        [comps setYear:0];
        NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
        [comps setYear:-5];
        NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

        [datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
        [datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

it showing five year date.......

Answer (score 0):

See the minimum time from the current date to one month:

```
NSDate* currentTime = [NSDate date];

[datePicker setMinimumDate:[currentTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:43200]];//min time +12:00 for the current date

[datePicker setMaximumDate:[currentTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:2592000]]; // max day (+ 30 )
```